# Problems adding items with contact references when authenticated as an app

Tags: api, authentication, podio

I'm trying to add an Item, where one of the fields is of type contact (user), to Podio.

I do not have the contact profile_id, only the name, so I need to search the contact to get the profile_id before adding.

The problem is that the /contact/ resources are inaccessible since I'm using app authentication.

The error is: "Authentication as app is not allowed for this method"

What is the recommended way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, the tricky part here is that you have just a name of the user. So you need to search this name first.

To be able to search you should be authenticated not as an app, but as a user with appropriate rights. I believe this is because search functions a [rate-limited](https://developers.podio.com/index/limits) **per user**. You may authenticate on client side, server side or just by entering user's email and password (see [documentation here](https://developers.podio.com/authentication)).

Then, when authenticated, just use search functions with the parameter `"ref_type": "profile"` to look for the user name within [space](https://developers.podio.com/doc/search/search-in-space-22479), [organisation](https://developers.podio.com/doc/search/search-in-organization-22487) or [globally](https://developers.podio.com/doc/search/search-globally-22488). Example for PHP-client:

```
$attributes = array(
    "query" => "John Doe",
    "ref_type" => "profile"
);
$results = PodioSearchResult::space( $space_id, $attributes ); // search in space
$results = PodioSearchResult::org( $org_id, $attributes ); // search in organisation
$results = PodioSearchResult::search( $attributes ); // search globally
```

Functions above will return an array of the most relative results found. There you can get a user id and other user info.

**Note** that technically several different users may have the same name, so there might be more that one result found. It will be up to you to choose one of them somehow.

Comment: Hey. Unfortunately as I expected. Thanks for the input.